# Implement “GetDirection” in Android Google map using Google Maps search

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to develop an Android application in that when the user just enters “starbucks” in the destination address, then using Google search find the closest address and substitute starbucks with real starbucks address. How to do it pro-grammatically!? Please see the figures [image][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to do that using the new *Google Places API*.  You need to register to the service in order to get a key allowing you to send requests. Then you can build an url, and get a JSON reply listing the places named Starbucks near Redmond: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=47.6743,-122.1220&radius=1&name=starbucks&client=CLIENTID&sensor=true&signature=SIGNATURE`

See the official website for API details and how to obtain a key:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/